# pip install returns nothing in command line

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I am setting up a Windows 10 machine. After installing python 2.7.10 I tried to install some libraries, but when I do

```
pip install grpcio
```

The command prompt returns nothing. I added --verbose and the execution terminates after printing

```
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
```

I tried to update pip using pip install --upgrade pip but I get exactly the same error. Also tried to execute get-pip but this is what I get

```
1 location(s) to search for versions of pip:
* https://pypi.org/simple/pip/
Fetching project page and analyzing links: https://pypi.org/simple/pip/
Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/pip/
Found index url https://pypi.org/simple
Looking up "https://pypi.org/simple/pip/" in the cache
Request header has "max_age" as 0, cache bypassed
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org:443
```

The problem is pretty much the same with easy_install.

I have connection to internet, pip is in Scripts folder and PATH contains the path to python2.7. --no-cache-data does not work. Do you have any ideas of what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was my Python installation. Had to do a nuclear uninstallation and then install again.